# JPA: Circular relations: diff between EclipseLink and Hiberante

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, eclipselink

We have an entity `Role` which could be either users or groups. In the groups we have set permissions. Therefore a user belongs to a group. Additionally groups can belong to other groups, i.e. one could make a hierarchy of permissions.

The idea is to store the relations from e.g. user -> group into a separate db table `role_ref`.

```
@Table(name = "role__parent")
@IdClass(RoleAssociationKey.class)
@Data
public class RoleAssociation implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "has_parent_role_id")
    private Role node;

    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "is_parent_for_role_id")
    private Role parent;
    ...
```

In EclipseLink I have in `Role`

```
// bi-directional many-to-many association to parents of a Role
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "node", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinTable(name = "role__parent", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "is_parent_for_role_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "has_parent_role_id") })
private List<RoleAssociation> parentRoles;
```

But Hibernate complains about this construct and I have severe problems to figure out the proper definition.

1. Hibernate fails to start because if `mappedBy` is specified than I cannot define `JoinTable`
2. I can remove the `JoinTable` Hibernate complains `left and right hand sides of a binary logic operator were incompatible`
3. If I remove `mappedBy` than I get ...`has the wrong number of column. should be 2`

I think the main problem is that `RoleAssociation` doesn't have its own `@Id` as a sequence. The Key is a compound of two ids - which are both required. If I would have it differently it might work. But since it works in EclipseLink I would say its a valid construct.

Is there a way to specify it to have it running in Hibernate as well?

Comment: EclipseLink isn't using the JoinTable annotation either - mappedBy tells JPA providers to use the mapping definition defined on the other side. You do not need and should not have the JoinTable annotation - it is wrong anyway. The error you get in hibernate seems to be query related, not the mapping.

Comment: The root cause and the solution for this issue can be found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/60040905/325868