# JPQL: Difference between EclipseLink and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

I already [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59388329/325868) about my situation and didn't find a proper solution. After some additional search I think I know the source problem although don't know how to resolve it. As mentioned I have:

```
@Table(name = "role__parent")
@IdClass(RoleAssociationKey.class)
@Data
public class RoleAssociation implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "has_parent_role_id")
    private Role node;

    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "is_parent_for_role_id")
    private Role parent;
    ...
}
@Data
class RoleAssociationKey implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int node;
    private int parent;
}
```

and I have

```
@Table(name = "role")
@Data
public class Role implements IRole {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "node", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private List<RoleAssociation> parentRoles;
    ...
```

Up to this point I think nothing special. I have the query:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Role.findParents", query = 
   "SELECT r FROM Role r JOIN RoleAssociation ra ON r.id = ra.parent.id WHERE ra.node.id = :id")
```

with the purpose to all set parents. When I compile it Hibernate complains`left and right hand sides of a binary logic operator were incompatible  [integer : component[node,parent]]`

Since the statement works in EclipseLink I have no clue how to change it into a working Hibernate one. Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How does RoleAssociationKey look like?

Comment: I've updated the q

Comment: I know that when you use CriteriaBuilder and you have a Join, in Eclipselink, the Join also does a Fetch, whereas in Hibernate, you have to add an explicit Fetch. I don't know if or how this relates to your issue.

Comment: @LeO - Try changing to "SELECT r FROM Role r JOIN r.parentRoles ra" and then specify the filter conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some struggels I finally figured the root cause of this problem. I'm aware that the SQL might be improved nevertheless I fail at other similar spots.

Hibernate requires to have a matching pair for `@OneToMany` relation.

In my query I refer to the `parent` of my role. The solution is

```
@Data
public class RoleAssociation implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "has_parent_role_id")
    @ManyToOne // <<<<==== rerequired for Hibernate
    private Role node;

    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "is_parent_for_role_id")
    @ManyToOne // <<<<==== rerequired for Hibernate
    private Role parent;
```

I have no clue why Hibernate complains while EclipseLink can fetch the required information. Nevertheless with this additional annoation the code works!

Comment: Different versions of JPA spec maybe? It might be that the necessity for the ManyToOne annotation has been relaxed in more modern versions of the spec since the mappedBy attribute in the OneToMany makes it 100% guaranteed that a ManyToOne is implied on the other side. In any case the situation here is that EclipseLink is more relaxed, Hibernate is technically correct in its demand.